# StructureMap Open Generic types with multiple types

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

so I've been trying to solve this issue for a couple of hours now. I searched the internet and looked at many Stackoverflow questions, but none could help me.

---

So I'm building a pipeline. The basic conecpt is the following:

- PipelineStore (Singleton) - Contains all registered `Pipeline`
- Pipeline[TEntity] (Transient) - One `Pipeline`per Entity (Account, Contact, ...)
- PipelineStep[TOperation, TInteractor, TEntity] (Transient) - Many Steps per `Pipeline`

`[]` representing the generic types.

---

I want to use StructureMap to create the Pipeline and the PipelineStep. So I created an auto factory called `IPipelineFactory` which has a single function:

```
IPipeline<TEntity> CreatePipeline<TEntity>() TEntity : EntityDTO, new();
```

I registered it in the Registry:

```
For<IPipelineFactory>().CreateFactory();
For(typeof(IPipeline<>))
    .Use(typeof(Pipeline<>))
    .Transient();
```

Then I get the IPipelineFactory injected and use it like the following:

```
public IPipeline<TEntity> NewPipeline<TEntity>() 
    where TEntity : EntityDTO, new()
{
    var pipeline = _pipelineFactory.CreatePipeline<TEntity>();
    _pipelines.Add(pipeline);
    return pipeline;
}
```

---

This works great, but when I try to do the same thing with the PipelineStep it fails:

```
public interface IPipelineStepFactory
{
    IPipelineStep<TOperation, TInteractor, TEntity> CreatePipelineStep<TOperation, TInteractor, TEntity>() 
        where TOperation : IOperation<TInteractor, TEntity> 
        where TInteractor : IInteractor<TEntity>
        where TEntity : EntityDTO, new();
}
```

And the registration:

```
For<IPipelineStepFactory>().CreateFactory();
For(typeof(IPipelineStep<,,>))
    .Use(typeof(PipelineStep<,,>));
```

usage:

```
public IAddPipeline<TEntity> Pipe<TOperation, TInteractor>()
    where TOperation : IOperation<TInteractor, TEntity>
    where TInteractor : IInteractor<TEntity>
{
    var step = PipelineStepFactory.CreatePipelineStep<TOperation, TInteractor, TEntity>();
    RegisteredSteps.Add(step);
    return this;
}
```

---

When I try to test the code it throws the following exception at runtime:

```
No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IPipelineStep<TestOperation, ITestInteractor, TestEntity>'

There is no configuration specified for IPipelineStep<TestOperation, ITestInteractor, TestEntity>
```

I thinks it's probably missing support for open generic types with multiple type arguments. Please let me know if there's any workarround to fix this issue. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out myself. The problem was, that the `PipelineStep` had slightly different generic type constraints which caused the issue. I changed

```
public class PipelineStep<TOperation, TInteractor, TEntity> : PipelineStepBase, IPipelineStep<TOperation, TInteractor, TEntity> 
    where TOperation : IOperation<TInteractor, TEntity>, IOperation<IInteractor<EntityDTO>, EntityDTO>
    where TInteractor : IInteractor<TEntity>, IInteractor<EntityDTO>
    where TEntity : EntityDTO
```

to

```
public class PipelineStep<TOperation, TInteractor, TEntity> : PipelineStepBase, IPipelineStep<TOperation, TInteractor, TEntity> 
        where TOperation : IOperation<TInteractor, TEntity>
        where TInteractor : IInteractor<TEntity>
        where TEntity : EntityDTO
```

and now it's working!